# WebView does not show up in File Template Library in Xcode 4.5?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode4.5

I am using Xcode 4.5, and am trying to add a UIWebView to the Main Storyboard. There is no WebView object in the File Template Library to use. Any suggestions?